# How to use context within same component file using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to access the state from one component to another. To do so i want to wrap contextprovider only to the component where state changes on clicking a button and return state from a usehook so that another component can access the state.

below is how the componnet looks without context applied,

```
function UploadButton () { //this is where state is set
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState(false); 
     
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}/>
            {isDialogOpen && <Upload/>}
        </>
    ); 
}

function UserButton() { //this is where state is accessed
    return (
        <Icon/> //this icon should be displayed only if !isDialogOpen
    );
}
```

With context looks like below, I have DialogContext within same file where UploadButton is.

```
 interface DialogCtxState {
     isDialogOpen: boolean;
     setIsDialogOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
 }

 const initialDialogState: DialogCtxState = {
     isDialogOpen: false,
     setIsDialogOpen: () => {},
 };

 const DialogContext = React.createContext<DialogCtxState>(
     initialDialogState  
 );

 export const DialogContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
     const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false); 

     return (
         <DialogContext.Provider
             value={{
                 isDialogOpen,
                 setIsDialogOpen,
             }}
         >
            {children}
         </DialogContext.Provider>
    );
}

function UploadButton () {
    const {isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen} = React.useContext(DialogContext);
     

    const handleClick = () => {
         setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
         console.log('isDialogOpen', isDialogOpen) //prints false here.
    }

    return (
        <DialogContextProvider>
            <>
                <Button onClick={handleClick}/>
                {isDialogOpen && <Upload/>} //this doesnt render on clicking button as isDialogOpen 
                //is false
            </>
        </DialogContextProvider>
    );
}
```

The above snippet doesn't render the Upload component as isDialogOpen is always false no matter if I click the button.

I am not knowing what is wrong. could someone help me with this? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you need to move your context provider one level higher in your react components in order to use `useContext` in you `UploadButton` component. You cannot place the context provider inside of `UploadButton` in order to use it's context. You need to move the provider into a parent component.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-context-provider-g2nhz?file=/src/App.tsx) demostrating it.

Comment: thanks but it is not updating. everything seems fine but this doesnt work.

Comment: @someuser2491 updated my answer with what I think is the solution to your issue